# Angular, how to calculate sum totals from array of income?

Tags: arrays, angular, sum, filtering, subtotal

Cannot calculate total sum of  **income** .
My result is total = 0 , but hoped to see "650" . Really can't understand what i do wrong :(

When i  `console.log(this.interfaceArray.map(t => t.income))` in console there are an empty array :

[image]

But if array is empty why then i got results in my table ?

[image]
Interface.ts

```
export interface userInterface {

    _id: string
    username: string
    income : number
    icnomeDate: Date
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Total income: {{sumOfIncome()}}</h1>
```

Component.ts :

```
import { userInterface} from '../shared/user.interface'
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';

interfaceArray : userInterface[]=[]

 userList(){
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.userService.interfaceArray = res as userInterface[]
      }
    )
  }

sumOfIncome(){
    return this.interfaceArray.map(t => t.income).reduce((a , b) => a + b, 0);

        //console.log(this.interfaceArray.map(t => t.income))
  }
```

Comment: create stackblitz please?

Comment: Could you please `console.log` the value of `t`? Maybe the `t` does not contain the necessary data.

Comment: Will try to console.log now

Comment: a `console.log(this.faceArray.map(t => t.website.income.websiteIncome))` can give you a clue

Comment: Appreciate your answers guys, updated my post . I simplified interface. When i ```console.log(this.interfaceArray.map(t => t.income))``` it returns empty array in console. But it is not empty - can see income data in table